# The logic of P values and rejecting

Tags: statistics

Could someone please explain the logic of the reasoning behind why we reject the $H_0$ if the $\alpha$ exceeds the $p$ value

What I understand is that $\alpha$ is the probability of making a type 1 error if $H_0$ is true.

$p$ value is the likelihood of getting a value more to the right or left of your test stat if the $H_0$ is true (probability of getting a test stat that favors $H_a$ more)

So if $\alpha>p$ value means we reject $H_0$

Then it must mean that if the probability of making an error while $H_0$ is true is larger than the probability of getting a value more the to the right of your test statistic then reject $H_0$. How does that logic add up? Could someone explain the reason behind the why we reject $H_0$?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you read the (short) section on p values in Shao's mathematical statistics. It's explained quite clearly

Comment: Your test is reject the null hypothesis when the result appears *too extreme* on the assumption the null hypothesis is true.  The alternative hypothesis helps you decide what counts as *extreme*. You decide $\alpha$ in advance and design the rejection region so  $\alpha$ is the probability of seeing results in the rejection region on the assumption the null hypothesis is true, thus quantifying *too*. $p$ is the probability of seeing the result you did see or one as or more extreme on the assumption the null hypothesis is true, so $p <a$ suggests the result seen would be in the rejection region

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind hypothesis testing is that if a hypothesis is true, it is far more probable that our data will be in agreement with it than not. However, it won't *always* be such, since evidence can be misleading. We set $\alpha$ to control the chance that we'll be mislead when the hypothesis is true.

It is traditional to set $\alpha=0.05$ but that is just a tradition. For example, at CERN LHC (particle accelerator that found the Higgs) they use different $p-$value cutoffs so as to control false positives.

The $p-$value just tells us the smallest $\alpha$ we'd need to have to not reject.

Conversely, by definition the $p-$value statistic has a $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ distribution, so it will fall below $\alpha$ exactly $\alpha$ percent of the time when $H_0$ is true.

Basically, its just another way of coming up with the rejection region. You can use case-specific cutoffs (e.g., T-statistic is greater than $t$) or convert to $p-$values which are uniformly interpretable.

Both approaches lead to the same thing, although I like $p-$values because they show the degree of disagreement.